# Proof verification : regarding pointwise and norm convergence of a fourier sequence of $L^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

if $\{H_n\}$ fourier sequence of an $L^2$ function $f$ converges almost everywhere to a function $g$ then  $f=g$ almost everywhere Where $H_n = n$th fourier series of $f$. could you verify the proof?

**Proof:**

By the containment of $L^p$ spaces see   David M. Bressoud's book (A Radical approach to Lebesgue's theory of Integration) on page 260 :

$ (\int_a^b |H_n|^p dx)^{\frac {1}{p}} \le (b-a)^{\frac {(q-p)}{pq}} (\int_a^b |H_n|^q dx)^{\frac {1}{q}}$
you can take p=1 and q=2

By Bessel's Inequality $\int_a^b |H_n|^2 dx \le \int_a^b |f|^2 dx $

This implies {$H_n $} and $f$ are in $L^1 \bigcap L^2$ over a bounded interval [a b] and {$H_n $} is  uniformly integrable and since $H_n -f$ converges  almost everywhere , one can apply Vitali Convergence theorem

It is also a known result in $L^2$ (Riesz-Fischer theorem) $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \int_a^b (H_n -f)^2 dx = 0$

and by the inequalities above :$\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \int_a^b |(H_n -f)|dx = 0$

by Vitali convergence theorem $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} \int_a^b |(H_n -f)|dx =\int_a^b \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} |(H_n -f)|dx= 0$

implying $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} (H_n -f) =0 $ almost everywhere

Therefore $ \lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} H_n = g = f$ almost everywhere

Comment: That seems a lot harder than: $H_n \to f$ in $L^2$ implies $H_{n_k} \to f$ a.e. for some subsequence. The result follows.

Comment: @zhw. You are right but the proof follows similar lines by showing the limit of the subsequence is f.

Comment: @stalker2133 : Your proof looks correct to me. You have not technically proved the required uniform integrability, but it's not difficult.

Comment: Actually the first inequality implies uniform integrability. You can replace (b-a) with $ \mu (b-a) $.

Comment: Just remember a measurable set can be approximated with countable union of intervals.